# Comparing Thousands of datetimes in a reasonable amount of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Long story short, I'm trying to calibrate a thermometer. I have a CSV from my reference thermometer with 16k records (CSV-A), and a CSV from the thermometer to be calibrated with about 52k records (CSV-B). I need to compare the records from CSV-B to the CSV-A to get the times where CSV-B is closest to CSV-A and store the time and value in a different array.

I believe that I have gotten the basic logic of checking the datetimes in place, but the problem seems to be the fact that I have to iterate through an array of 52,000 items 16,000 times. I've tried implementing both multiprocessing and multithreading, but the script has yet to finish running.

```
import numpy as np, csv, multiprocessing as mp
from datetime import datetime as d
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
d_rt_t = []
d_rh_t = []
d_dt = []
d_dh = []
d_rt = []
d_rh = []
nts = d.now().timestamp()
with open(f"calib_temp-{nts}.csv", 'w') as ctw:
    pass
with open(f"calib_humid-{nts}.csv", 'w') as chw:
    pass

def find_nearest(array, value):
    nearest = min(array, key=lambda x: abs(d.strptime(x[1], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f') - d.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
    return nearest
def comp_d_rt_t():
    for row in d_rt:
        pool = Pool()
        d_rt_t.append([pool.map(find_nearest, d_dt, row[1]),row[1]])
def comp_d_rh_t():
    for row in d_rh:
        d_rh_t.append([pool.map(find_nearest, d_dt, row[1]),row[1]])

#str2date = lambda x: d.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f')
#str2date2 = lambda x: d.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

with open("dht-temp.csv", 'r', newline='') as ddt:
    fr_dt = csv.reader(ddt, delimiter=',')
    for row in fr_dt:
        d_dt.append([row[0],row[1]])
ddt.close
with open("dht-humid.csv", 'r', newline='') as ddh:
    fr_dh = csv.reader(ddh, delimiter=',')
    for row in fr_dh:
        d_dh.append([row[0],row[1]])
ddh.close
with open("ref-temp.csv", 'r', newline='') as drt:
    fr_rt = csv.reader(drt, delimiter=',')
    for row in fr_rt:
        d_rt.append([row[0],row[1]])
drt.close
with open("ref-humid.csv", 'r', newline='') as drh:
    fr_rh = csv.reader(drh, delimiter=',')
    for row in fr_rh:
        d_rh.append([row[0],row[1]])
drh.close

p1 = Process(target=comp_d_rt_t, args=(d_dt,row[1]))
p2 = Process(target=comp_d_rh_t, args=(d_dh,row[1]))
    
p1.start()
p2.start()
    
p1.join()
p2.join()

print(d_rt_t)
with open(f"calib_temp-{nts}.csv", 'a', newline='') as ct:
    c = csv.writer(ct, delimiter = ',')
    for row in d_rt_t:
        dt = np.where(d_dt == row[1])
        rt = np.where(d_rt == row[1])
        print(rt)
        c.writerow([dt[0], rt[0]])
with open(f"calib_humid-{nts}.csv", 'a', newline='') as ch:
    c = csv.writer(ch, delimiter = ',')
    for row in d_rh_t:
        dh = np.where(d_dh == row[1])
        print(dh)
        rh = np.where(d_rh == row[1])
        print(rh)
        c.writerow([dh[0], rh[0]])
```

I moved the for loops around a bit, but before they just called numpy append which called the find_nearest method.

Comment: i would personally just ditch python and just yolo it and try to wade through the murky waters like an intrepid explorer into Rust-land and bare-metal territory. But that's only just my one and three-quarters cents, anyway.

Comment: `ddt.close` doesn't call close, it needs `ddt.close()`.  But `with` closes the file anyway so just delete all the `xxx.close`.  I would also convert all the data to `datetime` objects *once* so it doesn't have to be done in the `min` key computation every pass.

Comment: What's the point of `with open(f"calib_temp-{nts}.csv", 'w') as ctw:
    pass
with open(f"calib_humid-{nts}.csv", 'w') as chw:
    pass`? you open these files the immediately close them without extracting data. The only thing I can think of is if you're testing for if the file exists but there are other ways to do that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] with a few lines (10?) of sample data from each data file.

Comment: `multiprocessing` doesn't share memory so it has to write data file and process has to read data from file - and working with file is much slower then doing all this in memory. maybe it will be simpler to read all to pandas and run it without multiprocessing and without loops (if it is possible). `pandas` uses code created with `C/C++` so it may run faster.

Comment: Perhaps parse each string date into timestamps just once, right after you read the file?   The code as it is is probably repeatedly parsing the same string by doing it in `find_nearest`

Comment: There are good suggestion here, but I wonder about the approach itself.  You are trying to perform 832,000,000 comparisons in order to calibrate a thermometer.  Every thermometer I've ever worked with is a relatively slow device, whose output data changes slowly (on a typical time scale of 1-10 seconds).  As far as I can see, your massive calculation is an attempt to pick out measurements that are as near to simultaneous as possible.  Are you striving for an unattainable (or unnecessary) level of accuracy?

Comment: You have made your long story *too* short. My brain hurts looking at your code trying to correlate your various CSV files with what you call `CSV-A` and `CSV-B`. Moreover, you say, "I need to compare the records from CSV-B to the CSV-A to get the times where CSV-B is closest to CSV-A and store the time and value in a different array." But I find that very vague and can't tell from which CSV file the time/value pairs are coming from and what the final result might look like because you provide no sample data.